# how to add active class to li element in cakephp header.ctp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a header which displays page links via `<li>` and `<a>` tags.

Here is a portion of the header:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">
                  Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="items">
                  Explore
                </a>
              </li>
             </ul>
 </div>
```

How can I set the class of the `<li>` that belongs to the active link to active?
I have code elsewhere in my project that sets an active link, but it is setting it from an array and I can't figure out how to apply it here.

Here is the code that is working from another page:

```
           <?php
              foreach ($categories as $category_side){
            $cat_class = '';
            if (isset($active_category) && ($active_category==$category_side['Category']['id'])){
              $cat_class = 'active';
            }
            ?>
          <li>
            <a href="/categories/view/<?php echo $category_side['Category']['id']; ?>" class="category-item <?php echo $cat_class; ?>">

              <?php echo $category_side['Category']['name_'.$txt_lang]; ?>
                                  </a>
          </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

I found this [how to add active class in current page in CakePhp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161982/how-to-add-active-class-in-current-page-in-cakephp) but I can't figure out how to apply it to the first block of code above.

How can I convert the first block of code above, using PHP or CakePHP functions so that the active menu's `<li>` class is set to "active".

***Solution***

Following Sehdev's answer below (accepted answer), I was able to create a solution for assigning the active class, to the active hyperlink in the header menu.

The *controller* and *action* in combination were not enough, as some pages linked to the same controller and action, but were actually different rendered views.

The solution was to use $this->here to extract the current url, like so:

(tested in CakePHP 2.9.1)

```
<?php
$activeurl = $this->here;
?>

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item <?php echo (!empty($activeurl) && ($activeurl == '/'))?'active' :'inactive' ?>">
       <a class="nav-link" href="/">
         Home
       </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item <?php echo (!empty($activeurl) && ($activeurl == '/items'))?'active' :'inactive' ?>">
       <a class="nav-link" href="/items">
        Explore
       </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Cakephp version below 3.4.0**

You can use `$this->request->param`. This object contains all the requested parameters like current controller, action etc.

if you want to use current page controller and action you can use the following code.

```
$controller = $this->request->param['controller'];
$action = $this->request->param['action'];
```

So if your controller is Users and action is item, you can use

```
<li class="nav-item <?php echo (!empty($this->request->param['action']) && ($this->param['action']=='item') )?'active' :'inactive' ?>">
                <a class="nav-link" href="items">
                  Explore
                </a>
              </li>
```

**For Cakephp version above 3.4.0,** you can use

```
$controllerName = $this->request->getParam('controller');
```

**For Cakephp version 2.x**

```
$controller = $this->request->params['controller'];
```

Comment: This was a great help. Thanks. It didn't work for me, as some of the urls use the same Controler and Action ; but I managed modify your solution, making use of $this->here property, and it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

The request exposes routing parameters

If you are using **Cakephp version above 3.5.0**

```
$action = $this->request->getParam('action'); // Use to get action name

$controller =$this->request->getParam('controller'); //  Use to get controller name

<?php $active_class = ( in_array($action, ['dashboard']) && 
  $controller=='Users')?"class='active'":''; ?>

<li class="nav-item <?php echo $active_class; ?>">
    <a class="nav-link" href="items">
       Explore
    </a>
</li>
```

If you are using **Cakephp version below 3.4.0**

```
$controllerName = $this->request->params['controller'] or $this->request->param('controller');
$actionName = $this->request->params['action'] or $this->request->param('action');

<?php $active_class = ( in_array($actionName, array('dashboard')) && $controllerName=='users')?"class='active'":''; ?>

<li class="nav-item <?php echo $active_class; ?>">
    <a class="nav-link" href="items">
      Explore
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Unfortunately I couldn't get the below 3.4.0 version to work when I tried it, the class remained unchanged.

Comment: @Gary if you print $this->request->params['controller'] what is its output